# Putting logo and Title side by side

Tags: html, css

I m trying to align the logo and the title side by side so that the paragraph will go below . I tried float by it's not working .How can I easily do it ?(css noobs)

```
<div class="left-column" style="float:left; background-color:#FF0; margin-left:10px; margin-top:20px;" width = "515">
    <div class= "Payement" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
     <img src="images/Forma1copy.png" class="logo_page"/>
     <h2>Payement</h2>
     <p> We accept all major credit and debit cards including Mastercard,Visa, American Express, and Discover. 
 We accept Paypal as a method of payment. </p>
    </div>
    <div class= "shipement" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
     <img src="images/Forma1_0.png"  class="shipement_logo" />
     <h2>Shipement</h2>
     <p>Free continental shipping within 2-3 business days. 
Canadian shipping for $4.99. Shipped within 2-3 business days.</p>
    </div>
   <div class ="return_policy" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
     <img src="images/Forma1.png" class="return_policy" />
     <h2>Return Policy</h2>
     <p> If you are not completely satisfied with your bagels, return it. No questions asked. We will refund your full purchase price.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is the picture of what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpFSV.png)

[this is what i m trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6MtJ.png)

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and everything is align to left..is there other css or files that is changing it? Also no need to float just `text-align: left` though thats default i think you might have another css that is centering it

Comment: the logo and the title side by side so that the paragraph will go below

Comment: ah i see ill send code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class= "Payement" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
     <div style="display:flex">
     <img src="images/Forma1copy.png" class="logo_page"/>
     <h2>Payement</h2>
     </div>
     <p> We accept all major credit and debit cards including Mastercard,Visa, American Express, and Discover. 
 We accept Paypal as a method of payment. </p>
    </div>
```

Just wrap the img and h2 inside a div and gave style as display:flex

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use something about following code.

<div style="">
<div style="float:left;width:80px;height:50px;">
<img src="images/Forma1copy.png" class="logo_page"/>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:200px;text-align:left;">
     <h2>Payement</h2>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about the paragraph ? i will have to create another div so that i goes below ?

Comment: just use another div bellow the given code Or just use a p tag like as following                                                                                                        <div style="padding:20px;text-align:justify;">Some text you want to place</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to get the desired result. I think it is the easiest solution and the one that looks best.

```
<div class="left-column" style="float:left; background-color:#FF0; margin-left:10px; margin-top:20px;" width = "515">
  <div class= "Payement" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
    <div class = "flex-wrapper">
      <img src="images/Forma1copy.png" class="logo"/>
      <h2>Payement</h2>
      <p> We accept all major credit and debit cards including Mastercard,Visa, American Express, and Discover. 
        We accept Paypal as a method of payment. </p>     
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class= "shipement" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
    <div class = "flex-wrapper">
      <img src="images/Forma1_0.png"  class="logo" />
      <h2>Shipement</h2>
      <p>Free continental shipping within 2-3 business days. 
        Canadian shipping for $4.99. Shipped within 2-3 business days.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class ="return_policy" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
    <div class = "flex-wrapper">
      <img src="images/Forma1.png" class="logo" />
      <h2>Return Policy</h2>
      <p> If you are not completely satisfied with your bagels, return it. No questions asked. We will refund your full purchase price.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {

  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black; /* remove this line */

}

h2 {

  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;

}
```

[image: This is what the result looks like]

Comment: i like your answer but i have already solved it with the first answer that was posted . Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You should use:  `text-align: left;` instead of `float:left;`

Answer (score -1):

Float your images left:

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-column" style="background-color:#FF0; margin-left:10px; margin-top:20px;" width="515">
  <div class="Payement" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
    <img src="images/Forma1copy.png" class="logo_page" />
    <h2>Payement</h2>
    <p>We accept all major credit and debit cards including Mastercard,Visa, American Express, and Discover. We accept Paypal as a method of payment.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="shipement" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
    <img src="images/Forma1_0.png" class="shipement_logo" />
    <h2>Shipement</h2>
    <p>Free continental shipping within 2-3 business days. Canadian shipping for $4.99. Shipped within 2-3 business days.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="return_policy" style=" background-color:#D5D5D5">
    <img src="images/Forma1.png" class="return_policy" />
    <h2>Return Policy</h2>
    <p>If you are not completely satisfied with your bagels, return it. No questions asked. We will refund your full purchase price.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

all you need is something like this:

```
img, h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Obviously you can be more detailed like `class h2 , etc` OR you can do it inline like you are doing it now... though redundant (whatever you please)...but that should do it.

You can also do `flex` too on the parent div if you want to go more modern css3